# Селекторы: выбирать xml объекты на странице

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет.

Подскажите, как в `jQuery` выбирать `xml` объекты на странице. Если например в ie8 используется `vml`, то как выбрать например тег "`rvml:skew`" или "`?xml:namespace`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну в jQuery есть метод [$.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

А неймспейсы искать как-то так:

```
.find("[nodeName=z:row]")
```

где `z:row` заменяешь на своё.

Answer (score 0):

Экранируйте слэшем двоеточие в селекторе (т.е. двумя слэшами в строке).

```
console.log($("xml\\:namespace").length);
console.log($("rvml\\:skew").length);
```